# Resteasy Client Byte Array Null on Server

Tags: java, file-upload, jax-rs, resteasy, multipartform-data

I'm trying to send a byte array from my resteasy client to another service (also resteasy) but  my byte array is always null on the server.

Resteasy: 2.3.6.Final

And yes I AM including the resteasy-multipart-provider jar in my classpath.

Server Code:

```
public class PhotoServiceInputBean {
    private byte[] photo;

    public byte[] getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    @FormParam("photo")
    @PartType("application/octet-stream")
    public void setPhoto(byte[] data) {
        this.photo = data;
    }
}

@Adapter
@Path("/")
public class PhotoServiceAdapter {

    @POST
    @Path("/services/{id}/photos")
    @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
    @Produces(value = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
    public Response createPhoto(@PathParam("id") Long id, @MultipartForm PhotoServiceInputBean inputBean) {
        System.out.println(inputBean.getPhoto());
    }
}
```

My Client Code is as follows:

```
@Path("/services/{id}/photos")
public interface CreatePhotoProxy {

    @POST
    @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
    @Produces(value = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
    public ClientResponse<PhotoServiceOutputBean> createPhoto(@PathParam("id") Long id, @MultipartForm PhotoServiceInputBean inputBean);

}
```

And here is where I call it:

```
public void uploadPhoto() {
    byte[] imageData = getImageData();
    CreatePhotoProxy createPhotoProxy = ProxyFactory.create(CreatePhotoProxy.class, baseUrl);
    PhotoServiceInputBean photoServiceInputBean = new PhotoServiceInputBean();
    photoServiceInputBean.setPhoto(imageData);
    response = createPhotoProxy.createPhoto(listingId, photoServiceInputBean);
}
```

The content length on my request ends up being very small according to the org.apache.http debug logs (40 bytes) which even gzipped is obviously way too small for the image i am uploading (imageData.length is about 50k in the test I'm running).

I've tried registering all sorts of providers manually but I feel like they should be built in and I've had no success doing any of that anyways.  All help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After much debugging of the resteasy core code I've found the issue and corrected it.  It appears that there is a bug when your `@MultipartForm` bean has the annotations placed on the getter instead of the property itself, that is causing the http request to not be built properly.  I believe that this will happen regardless of whether you're using the `ApacheHttpClient4Executor` or the `URLConnectionClientExecutor`

My modified bean looks like so and works just fine now:

```
public class PhotoServiceInputBean {
    @FormParam("photo")
    @PartType("application/octet-stream")
    private byte[] photo;

    public byte[] getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(byte[] data) {
        this.photo = data;
    }
}
```

This was pretty brutal to track down and hopefully this will be helpful to anyone else who encounters this issue.